# In VSTO, when cancelling the Item_Send event for a Meeting, the Appointment gets deleted from the inbox

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

In VSTO, I handle the Send event on a MeetingItem.

When in the Outlook preview window, if I choose to "Accept-send response now" and set cancel=true when the send event fires, the send does not occur and the invite in my inbox remains unchanged.

If I choose "Accept-edit response before sending" it opens in a pop up window. If I set cancel=true when the send event fires, the meeting response is not sent and the popup window remians open, BUT the invite in my inbox still gets deleted. How do I stop the invite being deleted when the MeetingItem's send event is cancelled?

Comment: In the latter case, does an appointment get created in your Calendar folder?

Comment: An appointment appears as the invite arrives in my inbox.  I have Outlook configured to put them in as tentative until I respond otherwise.  If I respond in the preview pane, and I cancel the send then the invite stays in the invox. If I respond in the pop-out window and cancel the send, the invite gets deleted from the inbox.

Comment: Yes, but does the tentative appointment in the Calendar folder stay tentative, or change to busy?

Comment: yes the appointmet stays in the calendar as tentative, but the inbox invite is deleted. Then if I accept the invite in the popup which is still open and allow the send, the correct appointment in the calendar is updated.

Comment: I will investigate Before_Delete event to see if that needs to be cancelled.